# extending @font-face declaration from external css file

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I am using a web-font that is declared with @font-face in an external css file. The font service is setup such that I source the external css file and then just use the font in my css.  I cannot source the font file itself in my own @font-face definition.

Every time I use the web-font on my site, I add the same two style definitions to it.  So, my font use always looks something like this:

```
h2{
   font-family: 'Knockout 26 A';
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Adding the antialiasing and grayscale EVERY TIME I use the font seems unnecessarily redundant. Is there a way for me to extend the @font-face declaration from the external file in my own css?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to extend a `@font-face` declaration. According to the [current W3C recommendation for fonts (3 Oct 2013)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) `@font-face` requires the `font-family` and `src` descriptors or the declaration is invalid. Additionally, the descriptors are limited to:

- font-family
- src
- unicode-range
- font-variant
- font-feature-settings
- font-stretch
- font-weight
- font-style

so you wouldn't be able to use `webkit-font-smoothing` or `moz-osx-font-smoothing` anyway.

I recommend using a CSS preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) to cut down on the verbosity of CSS. But if you can't use those you'll just have to keep writing your CSS declarations as you currently are.

Comment: Very thorough answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) mixins. From lesscss.org:

`Mixins are a way of including ("mixing in") a bunch of properties from one rule-set into another rule-set.`

So for example you could write:

```
.knockout{
   font-family: 'Knockout 26 A';
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And add the mixin where you want to apply the font:

```
h2{
    .knockout;
}
```

**[More on mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-mixins)**

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's a really interesting concept. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require me to source additional files, but other than that, this does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I actually faced the same kind of issue because the `@font-face` declaration was made in an external CSS file that I couldn't control.

I also tried to override the @font-face declaration but it does not work.

So the solution in my case was actually to declare the `@font-face` **BEFORE** the inclusion of the external CSS file. The browser will then use my `@font-face` declaration and ignore the one in the external file.